# Generating document for a huge PHP file

Tags: phpdoc

I have a huge PHP File ( approx 2 MB). As its a third party file so can't change it. Now I want to generate documentation for it using automatic documentation generators.

I tried Doxygen, Apigen and PHP Documenter. but each of it hangs or exhaust the  memory.

Is there a way to generate documentation for this file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the memory limit setting in your php.ini

If this fails, you could split the file up into several new ones, and later "stitch" the output of the generator together.